# How To Visible DataGridView Columns Using Checkbox's C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

How Can I Visible and Invisible Columns in DataGridView By Checked and Unchecked Check box's using WinForm, C#.

[image]

Comment: The `DataGridViewColumn` has a `Visible` property. [How to: Hide Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-hide-columns-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) … try `dataGridView1.Columns["columnToHide"].Visible = false;` when the check box is checked and `true` if its not checked.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified in your question whether you are using WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 2):

For each of the Datagrid columns bind the Visibility property of the column to the IsChecked property of the appropriate checkbox.

Set the converter in the binding to use [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

(This solution assumes that you are using WPF...)

Answer (score 2):

In case of Windows Forms:

You can specifiy the visibility for each `DataGridViewColumn` by means of the `DataGridViewColumn.Visible` property, for example:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["nameOfColumnThatShouldBeInvisible"].Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
```

Also, you might want to evoke a rebind when the checkboxes that determine whether certain columns are displayed or not, get checked/unchecked:

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox1_CheckedChanged);

public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    dataGridView1.Columns["nameOfColumnThatShouldBeInvisible"].Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
    //rebind dataGridView1 so as to show/hide column for clicked checkbox
}
```